# Function that is made to remove round brackets does not work, Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have a function that takes in an argument, preferably a string, takes each value of the string and implements them as elements in a list. After that, it iterate's through the list and is supposed to delete/remove elements that are round brackets, so basically, these: `(` `)`. Here is the code:

```
def func(s):
    n = 0
    s = [i for i in s]
    for i in s:
        if s[n] == "(" or s[n] == ")":
            del s[n]
        else:
            n += 1
            continue
    return s
print(func("ubib0_)IUBi(biub()()()9uibib()((U*H)9g)*(GB(uG(*UV(V79V*&^&87vyutgivugyrxerdtufcviO)()(()()()(0()90Y*(g780(&*^(UV(08U970u9yUV())))))))))"))
```

However, the function stops the iteration and ends/returns the list early (when some round brackets are still there).

I also went with another way, a way that works:

```
def func(s):
    n = 0
    s = [i for i in s]
    s2 = [i for i in s if i != "(" and i != ")"]
    return s2
print(func("ubib0_)IUBi(biub()()()9uibib()((U*H)9g)*(GB(uG(*UV(V79V*&^&87vyutgivugyrxerdtufcviO)()(()()()(0()90Y*(g780(&*^(UV(08U970u9yUV())))))))))"))
```

Why does this work while the other way doesn't? They like they'd output the same result.
What am I doing wrong in the first example?

Comment: The first is *editing* while iterating.  Therefore the object being iterated is changing on each iteration, thus ending early.

Answer (score 1):

Your concept is correct, in that you either delete the current item or increment `n`.

Where you've gone wrong is that you're iterating over each letter which doesn't make sense given the above info. Changing `for i in s` to `while n < len(s)` will fix the problem.

A couple of things you may find useful:

- `list(s)` looks cleaner than `[i for i in s]`
- `i not in "()"` is another way to write `i != "(" and i != ")"`

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning when you're increasing `n`, `n` equals to `i`. But when you meet a bracket, `n` has the same value the next iteration, and `i` increases. It happens every time `s[n] == "(" or s[n] == ")"` and the difference between `n`'s and `i`'s values increases.

To work correctly you program needs to check every symbol in the list (string) for equality of either `'('` or `')'` using `s[n]`, but it doesn't happen because the iteration stops when `i` achieves the end of the list and `n` at that time is much less than `i` and it hasn't achieved the end of the list yet and hasn't checked all symbols.